# VisJs How to import json data without creating duplicate edges?

Tags: json, import, duplicates, gephi, vis.js

How can I import new json data (gephiJSON) without duplicating edges in my existing data?

My code is as simple as that:

```
var parsed = vis.network.gephiParser.parseGephi(gephiJSON, parserOptions);
nodes.update(parsed.nodes);
edges.update(parsed.edges);
```

I am afraid I did not find any option or function to avoid/check duplicates.

Appreciate any help.

*I have no control over the imported data to avoid duplicates.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Gephi API, but I know Gephi does not support duplicate edges. It automatically merges them when you import a graph file.

Comment: Yes. That is it. Indeed it automatically merges.

Answer (score 1):

I use nodes.update method only to update existing network. To create new ones I use nodes.add. So, it's important to check existing data in your network before trying to add. I used a double loop routine plus a splice method for the JSON to delete duplicated nodes and edges. My code was like this (please be patient with me, I'm new in JavaScript) :

```
function recibedatos() {
        if (http_request.readyState == 4) {
            if (http_request.status == 200) {
                fixedResponse = http_request.responseText;
                jsonObj = JSON.parse(fixedResponse); 
                try {
                    for (var i=0;i<jsonObj.nodos.length;i++) {
                        for (var j=0;j<nodes.length;j++) {
                            if (jsonObj.nodos[i].id==nodes.get()[j].id)  {
                                     jsonObj.nodos.splice(i,1);
                                      i-=1;
                                      break;
                            }
                        }
                     }
                     nodes.add(jsonObj.nodos);
                  }
                  catch (err) {
                      alert(err);
                  }
                  try {
                      for (var i=0;i<jsonObj.vinculos.length;i++) {

                          for (var j=0;j<edges.length;j++) {
                              if (jsonObj.vinculos[i].to==edges.get()[j].to && jsonObj.vinculos[i].from==edges.get()[j].from && jsonObj.vinculos[i].label==edges.get()[j].label)  {
                                  jsonObj.vinculos.splice(i,1);
                                  i-=1;
                                  break;
                              }
                          }

                      }
                      edges.add(jsonObj.vinculos);
                  }
                  catch (err) {
                      alert(err);
                  }
             } else {
                  alert("Ocurrio un problema con la URL.");
            }
            fixedResponse=null;
            jsonObj=null;
      }
}
```